# Using rust how can I convert a 2d array into a 2d vector?

Tags: arrays, vector, rust

Given a 2d array such as

```
let S = [
        [0,0,1,0,0],
        [0,0,1,0,0],
        [0,0,1,0,0],
        [0,0,1,0,0]];
```

How can I convert it into a 2d Vector?

```
Vec<Vec<i32>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2d array is `array` of `array`s, so to create 2d Vector you need to create `Vec` of `Vec`s. One way to do that is to iterate over the array and convert every item using `to_vec()` method, then `collect()` to `Vec`.

```
let s: Vec<_> = s.iter().map(|&e| e.to_vec()).collect();
```

Comment: Very clean I like it

Comment: You only need to say that it is a vector. No need to write the full type: `let s: Vec<_>`.